# How can the attacker exploit the blind SQL inject vulnerability apart from sleeping the server?

Tags: security, sql-injection, server-side-attacks

In one of my projects I discovered a blind-sql-injection vulnerability, that goes like this:

the url *index.php/company/lang/action* can be injected with some extra sql like this
*index.php/company'%20and%20''='/lang/action*

the only thing I've found the attacker can do is to sleep the server, eg.
*index.php/company'%20and%200=sleep(100)%20and%20'1'='1/lang/action*

What could be other options for the attacker?

Thanks

Comment: I've found that insertions like /company';drop%20table%20config;--/ for whatever reason don't work, so it's impossible to exec multiple queries, ie. the attacker will have to build the attack around 1 select statement

Comment: what's the point in looking for "other options for the attacker" instead of **patching the vulnerability right away?**